# Is there anyway to log post request using lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd

I need to log the post request body and check it on the log file , not just log the method , I'm using lighttpd.

I know that nginx can log this use "$request_body", can lighttpd to this?

I have been check the wiki, but seems can't find some way :(

here the wiki [Docs_ModAccessLog](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModAccessLog)

%q can not log post data.

Comment: Have you tried %b I'm not sure if this is the content length or the actual post body data.

Comment: Ah, a good question? I'll try the suggestion above. A recent doc suggests `%I` -- bytes incoming

Comment: Ah no, both only show the number of bytes, not the bytes themselves